# Alipay and Unionpay payment gateway doubts

Tags: payment-gateway

When we interface with Alipay/Unionpay, do we have the provision to let Alipay know that this amount needs to be authorized or charged completely. 
How does this work?

what does it determine for Alipay and UnionPay to charge the card or just authorize it? Or does Alipay and Unionpay only support charging the card and not authorizing it?

Please come up with your valuable suggestions.